# How to define and use many_to_many relationships in DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, orm, dbix-class

I have 3 tables in DB, simplified as that:

```
book        book_language       language
=====  <->> ============== <<-> ========
bookID      book_languageID     languageID
title       bookID              language
            languageID
```

With `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` I generated schema, where are corresponding Result classes:

```
Book
BookLanguage
Language
```

For some reasons `Loader` did not detect many_to_many relationship between those tables, so I defined relations myself like this in `Language` class:

```
package R::RMT::Result::Language;
...
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('books' => 'book_language_rel', 'bookid_rel');
```

and in `Book` class:

```
package R::RMT::Result::Book;
...
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('languages' => 'book_language_rel', 'languageid_rel');
```

Now I hoped to access all related languages as this:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=rkBook";
my $schema = R::RMT->connect( $dsn, 'user', 'pwd' );

my $book_rs = $schema->resultset('Book');
say $book_rs->languages();
```

But I got error:

```
Can't locate object method "languages" via package "DBIx::Class::ResultSet" at ...
```

What I got wrong? I tried clue together pieces from docs, but obviously I got something wrong. I never seen one complete example of how `many_to_many` relationship should work.

AFAIU, defining relationship in Result class should make an accessor in this class. How could I see all genereated accessors? If I try to dump ResultSet object with `Data::Printer` I see only accessors for columns, but no accessors for relationships.

If I try list relations with:

```
say $schema->source('Book')->relationships;
```

I don't see here `many_to_many` relations (also not those which are picked up by `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`), only `has_many`s and `belongs_to`s.

**Edit. Added simplest testcase:**

Create tables and populate with data

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `bookID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`),
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `language` (
  `languageID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`languageID`),
  KEY `language` (`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `book_language` (
  `book_languageID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `languageID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_languageID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `book_language` (`bookID`,`languageID`),
  CONSTRAINT `book_language_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`languageID`) REFERENCES `language` (`languageID`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `book_language_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`bookID`) REFERENCES `book` (`bookID`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO language (language) VALUES ('estonian'), ('english'), ('polish');
INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES ('Eesti rahva ennemuistsed jutud'), ('Estonska-polska slovar'), ('21 facts about...'), ('Englis-Polish Dictionary');
INSERT INTO book_language (bookID, languageID) VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,2),(4,3);
```

Generate schema with defaults:

```
dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib -o debug=1 My::Schema 'dbi:mysql:dbname=testbook' user password
```

Added `many_to_many`-definitions in `Book.pm`

```
# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07046 @ 2017-03-21 18:49:05
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:ipamXRkSe+HLXGdTGwzQ9w
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('languages' => 'book_languages', 'languageid');
```

And in `Language.pm`

```
# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07046 @ 2017-03-21 18:49:05
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:nZyaWdriRpgEWDAcO3+CFw
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('books' => 'book_languages', 'bookid');
```

Run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.014; use utf8::all;
use My::Schema;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=testbook";
my $schema = My::Schema->connect( $dsn, 'user', 'password' );

my $book_rs = $schema->resultset('Book');
say $book_rs->languages();
```

Comment: Has DBIC::Schema::Loader picked up the many-to-one relationships between book and book_language and between language and book_language? What are they called?

Comment: @DaveCross Yes, loader picked them up, they are both named `book_language_rel`

Comment: That's a slightly strange name for schema loader to choose. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: @DaveCross I have changed naming convetion by `inflect_singular` and `inflect_plural` options. But now generated without them and still got same error when tried to access `$book_rs->languages()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that `many_to_many` only generates helper methods (accessors) but are no 'real' relationships in the sense that you can't use them in join and prefetch parameters.

The problem with your sample code is that you try to call a result method (the generated 'languages') on a resultset object.

Calling `$rs->first->languages` for example will work.

If you want all languages of all books in your `$book_rs` you'd have to use `search_related` on the two relationships forming the `many_to_many`. This won't hit the database if you prefetch the two or don't fetch the rs before in which case an optimized query is built and executed.

Answer (score 2):

Many to many relationships build on the existing "has_many" and "belongs_to" relationships. If they aren't set up correctly, the many_to_many relationships won't work either. In your situation, I'd expect DBIC::Schema::Loader to generate the following relationships:

In Book.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( 'book_languages'
                       'Your::DBIC::Schema::BookLanguages',
                       'bookID' );
```

In Language.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( 'book_languages'
                       'Your::DBIC::Schema::BookLanguages',
                       'languageID' );
```

In BookLanguage.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( 'book'.,
                         'Your::DBIC::Schema::Book' );
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( 'language',
                         'Your::DBIC::Schema::Language' );
```

Then you can manually add the following:

In Book.pm

```
__PACKAGE->many_to_many( 'languages',
                         'book_languages',
                         'language' );
```

In Language.pm

```
__PACKAGE->many_to_many( 'books',
                         'book_languages',
                         'book' );
```

Comment: `has_many` name is `book_languages`, but in `many_to_many` you refer to `book_language`. Typo? Or am I missing some? Btw, one `multi_to_multi` is picked up by Loader too, but it gives me same error/result...

Comment: Sorry, yes, typo. Fixed now.

Comment: I added to question whole testcase. Maybe you can try it and look closer, where is err.